# Matplotlib: Error in this code while plotting sine function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,10)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
```

(most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-18-d8b592bf313e>", line 1, in <module>
    plt.plot(x,y)

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `matplotlib.pyplot` not `matplotlib`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import pyplot module from matplotlib package:
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated :)